# WYSIWYG editor component for GWT

Tags: java, gwt, editor, components, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a WYSIWYG editor component for GWT or which is easy to use in a GWT generated page. Any clue?

I took a look at CKEditor, but I don't know if it's easy to integrate with GWT. If you have done something like this, I'm interested in your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CKEditor has been integrated with GWT ([gwt-ckeditor](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ckeditor/), [vaadin-ckeditor](http://code.google.com/p/vaadin-ckeditor/)), as has TinyMCE ([tinymce-gwt](http://code.google.com/p/tinymce-gwt/), [gwt-tinymce](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-tinymce/)) and several other WYSIWYG editors ([gwt-html-editor](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-html-editor/), etc...).

Comment: All projects are dear as far as I can see from the project activities, only vaadin-ckeditor is still active.
Did anyone succeed in using the vaadin-ckeditor in a non vaadin (pure gwt) context?

Comment: @PapickG.Taboada when this answer was written nearly two years ago, there was a much closer alignment between Vaadin and pure GWT and the vaadin-ckeditor worked well for non-vaadin projects. From my understanding they've diverged quite a bit and most vaadin components are no longer compatible with plain GWT.

Answer (score 2):

**gdbe Google-Docs Base Editor**

> The Google-Docs Base Editor (GDBE) is a web based text editor built to
>   model the existing Google-Docs editors. It integrates with Google-Docs
>   via the GData API.
>
> The purpose of GDBE is to give developers a starting point for
>   building editors for different document types that can be integrated
>   into Google's editor suite.
>
> GDBE is written in Java and makes use of the GData API to communicate
>   with Google Docs. The client side is implemented GWT and the server
>   side is built with AppEngine in mind.

http://code.google.com/p/gdbe/